# Need to create a animation with javascript (mimic gif) with jpgs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animated-gif

I'm having a buch of jpegs coming from a old flash animation.
They're named from 1000.jpg to 1092.jpg playing in that order.
I tried to create a .gif animation with those pictures but the gif was simply to big and the quality was horrible.

This is why I tried to use jQuery to animate those jpegs to mimic this gif animation.

This is the code I found here on stackoverflow

```
$("#logo").click(function() {
var $logo = $(this), src = $logo.attr("src");
var index = src.indexOf('.jpg');
var step = +src.slice(index-4, index);

function frame() {
    step++;
    if(step < 93) {
        var newSrc = src.slice(0, index-4) + step + ".jpg";
        console.log(newSrc);
        $logo.attr('src', newSrc);
        setTimeout(frame, 50);
    }
}

frame();
});
```

But it's not working ... the animation time was 0,03 seconds each and I had the picture as "img id="logo" src="images/1000.jpg"/" (for sure with the <> ) but it's not working or changing the src.

Any help make that work?
Thanks

Edit: Please help once again as this is driving me crazy. 
I tried the sprite thing but that doesnt work as you can see the fade how the background gets moved.

I really just need to mimic that gif, it's just a simple gif consisting out of 93 pics. It's just an animation where a face changes to another face ...

Comment: How large is the average / the largest .jpg file? Maybe you need to preload them?

Comment: I recommend you to make a sprite from your images and change not the src attribute, but background position instead. This is better for performance and has less loading time.

Comment: Please provide your html code, too (in an indented code section), but only the code neccessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: well, this is actually how I tried it several times http://jsfiddle.net/DgZ4M/27/ the same code also locally executed

Comment: `Fehler: Image corrupt or truncated: http://iflorian.com/test/image/1040.jpg
Quelldatei: http://iflorian.com/test/image/1040.jpg
Zeile: 0` -> The jsfiddle does seem to work... It just doesn't find the image files. Also, try it with a longer (3 sec) interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
You are trying to set the `src` of a `div`. Set the `src` of an `img` instead:

<div>
  <img id="logo" src="mypath/mylittlepony.jpg">
</div>
*/
this doesn't apply anymore since the question was edited...
```

Now [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgZ4M/56/) works as you want it, at least in my browser (Firefox 4.0.1).

**EDIT**
start after load: look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgZ4M/72/)
start after load and endless loop: look at [this final JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgZ4M/74/)
extra gimmick: [back and forth](http://jsfiddle.net/DgZ4M/76/)

You still do have a problem with caching. The animation is fluid only if all the images are cached. You could preload them by putting them as 1-px-imgs on your page.

```
<img src="http://iflorian.com/test/image/1000.jpg" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
<img src="http://iflorian.com/test/image/1001.jpg" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
<img src="http://iflorian.com/test/image/1002.jpg" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
...
<img src="http://iflorian.com/test/image/1050.jpg" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
```

Of course you can do this via JQuery, but then you could simply hold an array of image objects which replace the original image in the timer function.

Comment: That worked now =) Thank you very much! One last thing, how can I make it to start working after load and how to make an endless loop?

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I really appreciate your time, effort and everything! You helped me a lot :-)

Comment: Okay, I'm still having problems here! It seems as that way to animate those graphics is not working in Firefox and Internet Explorer. Any Idea on how to do that for those browsers as well?

Comment: It works in my firefox, once all the images are loaded in cache. Before that, it "doesn't work", either, but only because the images don't get loaded fast enough. You should preload the images and check your javascript error console, too...

Answer (score 0):

Just check on your Web Browsers' Error Console if Javascript is raising any error... because if any part of your JS raises an exception and fails to run then the effect might also fail.
Happened to me at occassions.